# Supply custom options to DoctrineModule's ObjectRepository

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to work my path through the source of [DoctrineModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule) for Zend2, since comprehensive documentation for beginners is virtually non-existent.

In there, I found a custom authentication adapter, [ObjectRepository](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Authentication/Adapter/ObjectRepository.php). This class takes an object of [DoctrineModule\Options\Authentication](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineModule/Options/Authentication.php). All I need to set the `credentialCallable` value to a custom, [BCrypt](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.crypt.password.html#bcrypt)-based function.

I wrote a class for my controllers to wrap the adapter:

```
namespace User\Controller\Plugin;

class UserAuthentication extends AbstractPlugin {
    protected $_authAdapter = null;
    protected $_authService = null;

    public function __construct($authAdapter) {
        $this->setAuthAdapter($authAdapter);
    }
    // More setters/getters
}
```

Now I need to configure the module in a way that this call here will give me a valid instance.

```
$uAuth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('User\Controller\Plugin\UserAuthentication');
```

So naturally, I will have to work with the module condifguration. But here I am completely and entirely stuck, as I could not find any hint on how to create the instances of the classes properly. This is what I came up with so far:

```
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            'User\Event\Authentication' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'userAuthenticationPlugin' => 'User\Controller\Plugin\UserAuthentication',
                ),
            ),
            'User\Controller\Plugin\UserAuthentication' => array(
                'parameters' => array(
                    'authAdapter' => 'DoctrineModule\Authentication\Adapter\ObjectRepository'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'DoctrineModule\Authentication\Adapter\ObjectRepository' => function ($sm) {
                /// ????
            },
            'DoctrineModule\Options\Authentication' => function($sm) {                
                /// ????
            },
        ),
    ),
);
```

So I have no idea what to fill in there, or if this is even the correct way to go. Perhaps I go the wrong path entirely, since when executing this, I get:

```
An abstract factory could not create an instance of usercontrollerpluginuserauthentication(alias: User\Controller\Plugin\UserAuthentication).
```

I appreciate any ideas and hints. And please don't direct me to `ZfcUser` or similar, I want/need to implement this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not worked with `Di` in ZF2, yet. But here is how I use the DoctrineModule `ObjectRepository` in ZF2.

In my `Module.php` I have a factory for the AuthenticationService, just like you have an AuthenticationService. In the Factory I create a new `ObjectRepository` with all values it requires.

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'AuthService' => function($services) {
                $entityManager = $services->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
                $doctrineAuthAdapter = new ObjectRepository(array(
                    'objectManager' => $entityManager,
                    'identityClass' => 'Auth\Entity\User',
                    'identityProperty' => 'username',
                    'credentialProperty' => 'password',
                    'credentialCallable' => function($identity, $credential) {
                        return md5($identity->salt . $credential);
                    }, // this function makes the password hash salted
                       // you could also just use return md5($credential);
                ));

                // my AuthenticationService uses the entity manager
                // and the ObjectRepository
                $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                $authService->setEntityManager($entityManager);
                $authService->setAdapter($doctrineAuthAdapter);

                return $authService;
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

The `AuthenticationService` is basically an extension of Zend's AuthenticationService with some additional methods, I found useful (and `Zfc` uses, because I peeked from there). For brevitiy’s sake, I removed the implementations, but left the declarations to allow you to see what I thought could be useful in the service.

```
<?php

namespace Auth\Service;

use Application\EntityManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService as ZendAuthenticationService;

use Auth\Entity\User;

class AuthenticationService extends ZendAuthenticationService implements EntityManagerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * This method makes sure that we always get a User-object
     * we can call methods on. In case of a non-authorized user
     * we will receive a dummy object without storage or with
     * session storage. So data might be lost!
     */
    public function getIdentity()
    {
        $storage = $this->getStorage();

        if ($storage->isEmpty()) {
            return new \Auth\Entity\User\Dummy();
        }

        $userid = $storage->read();

        $user = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Auth\Entity\User', $userid);

        if ($user == null) {
            return new \Auth\Entity\User\Dummy();
        } else {
            return $user;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register a new user to the system. The user password will by hashed before
     * it will be saved to the database.
     */
    public function register(User $user)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Reset the users password to a random value and send an e-mail to the
     * user containing the new password.
     */
    public function resetPassword(User $user)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Delete a users account from the database. This does not really delete the
     * user, as there are too many connections to all other tables, but rather
     * deletes all personal information from the user records.
     */
    public function delete(User $user)
    {

    }

    public function setEntityManager(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }
}
```

Then in the Controller I can use the following piece of code to login a user:

```
// getAuthService() just calls $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService')

$this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
     ->setIdentityValue($username)
     ->setCredentialValue($password);

$result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();

foreach($result->getMessages() as $message) {
    $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage($message);
}

if ($result->isValid()) {
     $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->write($result->getIdentity()->getId());
     return true;
 } else {
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks. I'll try it soon. I also saw that my plugin is actually an AuthService an I should use is as such.

Comment: This answer works, but it's a bit clumsy. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092091/zend-2-doctrine-2-auth-adapter/12101461#12101461 for a simpler approach.