# Zend2 + Doctrine2 Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I would like to have authentication using Doctrine 2 and ZF2. To get some help I used [Zend 2 + doctrine 2 Auth Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092091/zend-2-doctrine-2-auth-adapter/15174551), but every time I call the `$authService->authenticate($adapter);` I get an error that the class '' does not exist.

It seems that the config from my module.config.php won#t be used. It shows like this:

```
'authenticationadapter' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'objectManager' => 'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default',
            'identityClass' => 'Profile\Entity\User',
            'identityProperty' => 'username',
            'credentialProperty' => 'password',
        ),
    ),
```

But if i made a var_dump on the authService all sets are null.
In my service where I want to do the login I call

```
$authAdapter = $this->getAuthAdapter();
$authAdapter->setIdentityValue($username);
$authAdapter->setCredentialValue($password);
```

A dump from the $authAdapter tells me that the IdentityValue and the CredentialValue
are set correctly.

The other things in the $authAdabter are:

```
protected 'options' => 
    object(DoctrineModule\Options\Authentication)[281]
      protected 'objectManager' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[248]
          private 'config' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)[250]
              ...
          private 'conn' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Connection)[252]
              ...
          private 'metadataFactory' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory)[266]
              ...
          private 'repositories' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'unitOfWork' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork)[267]
              ...
          private 'eventManager' => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\EventManager)[242]
              ...
          private 'hydrators' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'proxyFactory' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory)[268]
              ...
          private 'expressionBuilder' => null
          private 'closed' => boolean false
          private 'filterCollection' => null
      protected 'objectRepository' => null
      protected 'identityClass' => null
      protected 'identityProperty' => null
      protected 'credentialProperty' => null
      protected 'credentialCallable' => null
      protected 'classMetadata' => null
      protected 'storage' => null
      protected '__strictMode__' => boolean true
  protected 'authenticationResultInfo' => null
```

The getAuthAdapter shows like this:

```
public function getAuthAdapter()
{
    if (null === $this->authAdapter) {
        $this->authAdapter = $this->getServiceManager()
            ->get('doctrine.authenticationadapter.ormdefault');
    }
    return $this->authAdapter;
}
```

So can some one tell me how to set the options correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong configuration values. If you look at the DoctrineORM documentation, they use the following to set the configuration for the authentication adapter:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'authentication' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'object_manager' => 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
            'identity_class' => 'Application\Entity\User',
            'identity_property' => 'email',
            'credential_property' => 'password',
        ),
    ),
)
```

So, instead of using `authenticationadapter` use `authentication` in your module.config.php; instead of using `objectManager` use `object_manager`, etc.

---

In your Module.php, you will need to add this:

```
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

...

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => function($serviceManager) {
                return $serviceManager->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');

            }
        )
    );
}
```

And in your controller, you can access the Adapter using:

```
$authService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');

$adapter = $authService->getAdapter();
$adapter->setIdentityValue($data['login']);
$adapter->setCredentialValue($data['password']);
```

Please follow the [documentation](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/authentication.md).

Comment: Okay I change it but now it tells me `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.authentication.orm_default`. I change the getter to `public function getAuthAdapter()
    {
        if (null === $this->authAdapter) {
            $this->authAdapter = $this->getServiceManager()
                ->get('doctrine.authentication.orm_default');
        }
        return $this->authAdapter;`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now is only one problem left. After `$authResult = $authService->authenticate();` I get a empty page. No error, nothing.

Comment: In your Entity, are you implementing any interfaces or extending any base classes?

Comment: No only the entity generated with `vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --from-database annotation module/Profile/src/ --namespace="Profile\\Entity\\"
` and the setter and getter.

Comment: Okay I don't know what the error was but now it works. Thanks for your great help and please excuse me for my english it's not my native language.

Comment: @MatusvonMatushausen Feel free to mark this question as resolved if you have your answer :)

Comment: When I find the link to do that :) Or only edit the title with 'resolved:' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' in Module.php as suggested by Hohner, this will not work with the BjyAuthorize Module roles and ACL. BjyAuthorize will default to its own default configuration of the Authentication service which uses 'ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\Db'. To get BjyAuthorize to use the Doctrine identity replace it with (or add ) 'zfcuser_auth_service' as follows:

```
'zfcuser_auth_service' => function ($serviceManager) {
    return  $authenticationService = $serviceManager->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');
},
```

Then you also use it in the controller in a similar way:

```
$authService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get( 'zfcuser_auth_service' );
```